# How to calculate an orthonormal basis for a matrix?

Tags: matrices, computational-complexity, orthonormal

Are there any specific, easy to compute, algorithms to build an orthonormal basis for a matrix in which each column has length one?

Comment: Is Gram-Schmidt what you're looking for? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: You should look up the gram schmidt algorithm.

Comment: Do the column of the matrix need to be orthogonal as well or are you just looking for an orthonormal basis such that, expressed in that basis, the columns of the matrix have length one?

Comment: What I intend to do is exactly this:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/orth.html
"B = orth(A) computes an orthonormal basis for the range of A."

Comment: From the documentation for `orth`, "these functions use different versions of the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization algorithm" Use the columns of your matrix as the basis vectors.